# jquery and unordered list

Tags: jquery

I want to have the same functionality of select in HTML but using div and unordered list.

When the page load, the name of the button should be the the element li which has class="selected". It means that I have to change html of `selector_button` to one that has the class selected in the li tag.

Also How can I make the unordered list hide when user clicks on any part of the page or selects another item from the list.

how can i achieve this?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/cZ36w/2/

JS thus far:

```
$('#select_button').html();

$('#selector_button').click(function() {
    $('#selector_list').show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="selector_button">
    <ul style="display:none;" id="selector_list">
        <li class="option-selected" title="7">Everything</li>
        <li title="1">A</li>
        <li title="4">B</li>
        <li title="9">C</li>
        <li title="8">D</li>
        <li title="22">E</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.option-selected
{
    color:#c0c0c0;
}
```

Comment: The code isn't that much. Why not just paste it into the question? Same goes for the answers thus far (Akhil and NAVEED). A link to a fiddle that may not be around forever is neither a question nor an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you want to use your `<ul>` list as html select box.

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/cZ36w/5/

**CSS:** Same

**HTML:** Remove `style="display:none;"` from `<ul>`

**jQuery**:

```
$('#selector_button li').hide();
$('#selector_button li.option-selected').show();


$('#selector_button ul li').hover(function() {
    $('#selector_button ul li').show(); 
});

$('#selector_button ul li').mouseout(function() {
    $('#selector_button li').hide();
    $('#selector_button li.option-selected').show();
});


$('#selector_button ul li').click(function() {
    $('#selector_button ul li').removeClass('option-selected'); 
    $(this).addClass('option-selected'); 
});
```

It is not perfect but it will give you a direction to achieve your goal.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $("#bdiv").buttonset();
   $(".select").button().click(function() {$("#selector_list").toggle();})

$(".selectarrow").button({text: false,icons: {primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"}
}).click(function() {$("#selector_list").toggle();})

});
```

See a demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZ36w/4/).

Comment: generally you should explain your answer, rather than simply linking to it.